# Python 3 reading values from a CSV then parsing them into a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So im trying to read CSV data, load it into an array then parse it into 3 values in another function, using python 3. I am a novice and not very good at coding. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

So my CSV looks like this:

```
SPXS,2165,sell
TMV,388,sell
TMF,5415,buy
UPRO,1970,buy
```

and my code looks like this:

```
with open('out.txt', "r") as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  x = []
  y = []
  z = []
for row in reader:
  x.append(row[0])
  y.append(row[1])
  z.append(row[2])
  api.submit_order(row['x'], row['y'], row['z'], 'market', 'day')
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/alpaca/passiv_autobuy_hack4.py", line 126, in <module>
    for row in reader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

It's pretty close as when i add the below in a seperate test file i get the below output.

Extra Code:

```
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)

print(row[0])
print(row[1])
print(row[2])
```

Extra Output:

```
['SPXS', 'TMV', 'TMF', 'UPRO']
['2165', '388', '5415', '1970']
['sell', 'sell', 'buy', 'buy']
UPRO
1970
buy
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there ! The `for` loop is run outside the `with` block. Thus, the file is already closed when you try to iterate it.

To make it work, change your code to :

```
with open('out.txt', "r") as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  x = []
  y = []
  z = []
  for row in reader:
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])
    z.append(row[2])
    api.submit_order(row['x'], row['y'], row['z'], 'market', 'day')
```